# How do I send out an email every Monday at 8:00am?

Tags: rules

How do I send out an email every Monday at 8:00am using rules?

Answer (score 1):

For finer grained control over scheduled jobs, you sould have a look at the [Elysia cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) module. Drupal out of the box is not capable of that degree of scheduling control.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Rule Scheduler and action 'Schedule Component Evaluation' to call the same component "+1 week" after sending the first e-mail exactly on Monday 8AM

Comment: Thank you Achilleas01.  This solution will work for me.  Could you let me know I would schedule this to run every Monday at 8am.  Thanks.

Comment: You will need one rule and one component. The component will have only one action to schedule component evaluation of itself +1 week and send e-mail.
The rule (you have to set an event like a user is created) will have an action to schedule component evaluation (you choose the component ) next Monday 8AM. 
CHECK THIS VIDEO FOR HELP 
http://nodeone.se/sv/node/772

Comment: Thank you Achilleas01.  This resolved my issue.  Thank you very much for your help.